# CSS arc rounded at the ends

Tags: css

I'm trying to draw an animated arc around a CSS styled text, which looks like a rounded icon.

Since it could be either an arc or a circle (because the rounded icon inside would hide the internal part of it), there are several solutions using only CSS, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835477/drawing-animated-arc-with-pure-css#answer-18839706), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415651/half-circle-with-css-border-outline-only#answer-22415694).

But I would like the line to be rounded at the ends. Something like this:

[image]

I'm not sure if it is possible. Any ideas?

Comment: What about using the `<canvas>` element?

Comment: @j08691 - Yes, this is my next option :)

Comment: Your next option should be svg IMHO http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5

Comment: Should this be animated or is it always static 270° like this?

Comment: @Xufox - Animated. I forgot to say it. I've updated my question.

Comment: @SimonPlus - Well, I think that I just need http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - All right, but what's the reason? Just browser compatibility? or memory/CPU waist too?

Comment: No, use Canvas! Forget about SVG!

Comment: Yeah, the only reason I proposed svg was because I thought canvas doesn't have a way to set the lineCap and svg does... Seems I was wrong ;) [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/4_6_canvas_linecap.html)

Comment: Xufox, @RokoC.Buljan  - You'll drive my crazy :P

Comment: https://youtu.be/SeLOt_BRAqc?list=PLQWB7UtRMkHP4rQ4CVaCsP2mv3GC_HGFX ruff but useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/k6d17fez/1/

Okay, so I ripped off part of [this already working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835477/drawing-animated-arc-with-pure-css#answer-18839706) and added these two blocks of code:

```css
.wrapper::after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
    background:#004466;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:relative;
    left:123px;
    z-index:1000;
}

.wrapper .spinner::after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
    background:#004466;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:relative;
    left:118px;
    top:-5px;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

It essentially adds two little circles at the ends of the circumference of the pie.

This is what it looks like in Firefox 37.0.1:

[image: Rounded Corners]

This solution may be a little bit “quick and dirty” but it does the job. Of course Canvas is far more suitable for this.

Comment: I just see a dot in your fiddle.

Comment: What?! It looks okay in Firefox 37.0.1…

Comment: @Manolo probably cause you need to see it in Firefox and add -vendor-prefixes for other browsers

Comment: @Xufox - Yes, it looks okay in Firefox. I'll mark as answered, but I'll finally go with canvas.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a canvas way of drawing it with an animation. A key part is being able to round the line's end caps with `context.lineCap = "round";`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2
var radius = 50;
var startAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * -90
var endAngle = 180
context.lineWidth = 15;
context.lineCap = "round";
var ctr = -90;
var clr = setInterval(function () {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150); // clear canvas
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, (Math.PI / 180) * ctr, false);
    context.stroke();
    ctr++;
    if (ctr == endAngle) clearInterval(clr)
}, 10)
```

```css
canvas {
    border:1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yeah, I already knew how to do it. I asked about a CSS solution. Anyway +1 for your work.