# How to create a circular countdown timer using HTML, CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

Currently, I am working on a quiz game and in that, for each question, I wish to place a countdown timer. I got some plugins, but I  wish if I could create it myself. What I am trying to create looks like the one in the image below.Can you please tell me how I can do it?

Is there a way to assign a border to only up to a specified percentage of the perimeter, so that I could give a border, first in full, and then as each second advances, I can keep decreasing/increasing it so that I would get it in the perfect way.

The timer I wish to create should look somewhat like this (hope you understand how its blue border will increase every second):

[image]

Comment: We're not here to do the coding for you. What have you tried? We're are here to guide/help you with your coding problems not do all work for you. Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I never asked you to do the whole coding for me brother.I just wanted to know whether there is any way to give circular border to only upto a certain width.Thank you.

Comment: almost the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835477/drawing-animated-arc-with-pure-css

Comment: Are you looking for: https://github.com/PragmaticMates/jquery-final-countdown ?

Comment: May not be 100% exactly as you want but you should get some ideas here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059190/html5-css3-circle-with-partial-border/13059412#13059412

Answer (score 59):

Here is something i was playing around with a while ago. It uses a combination of SVG, css transitions and javascript. You should be able to rip it apart and use as a starting point...

```js
/**
* The setTimeout({},0) is a workaround for what appears to be a bug in StackSnippets.
* It should not be required. See JSFiddle version.
*/

setTimeout(function() { 

  var time = 10; /* how long the timer will run (seconds) */
  var initialOffset = '440';
  var i = 1

  /* Need initial run as interval hasn't yet occured... */
  $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      $('h2').text(i);
      if (i == time) {      
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
      }
      $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
      i++;  
  }, 1000);

}, 0)
```

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item html">
    <h2>0</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="70" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/wz32sy7y/558/)**

Comment: Why between 0 and 1 there's no movement? ;)

Comment: :) I know! Great use of web technologies btw, upvoted!!

Comment: can any one guide me how to show numbers in revers format like from 10 to 0. I want to make reverse countdown.

Comment: can you tell me how to start timer using function with starting animation from 0. http://jsfiddle.net/sQx4H/119/

Comment: How did you get 440?

Comment: @Toniq The radius(`r`) of the circle is ~70 which creates a circumference of 440.

Answer (score -2):

you should look at the jquery plugin Knob https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob, generated canvas circular input, and set timer behavior like :

```
var time = 0,
    maxTime = 60;
$('#dial').knob({
  readOnly : true,
  thickness : 0.1,
  max : maxTime
});


setInterval(function() {
  if(time>maxTime) time = 0;
  time++;
  $('#dial')
        .val(time)
        .trigger('change');
}, 1000);
```

I made a codepen here : http://codepen.io/pik_at/pen/azeYRg